# Is there a way to write TensorFlow checkpoints asynchronously?

Tags: tensorflow

Currently I make checkpoints during training like this (pseudocode):

```
while(training):
    model.train()

    if it_is_time_for_validation():
        metrics = model.validate()

        if metrics.are_good():
             saver = tf.train.Saver()
             res = saver.save(sess=session, save_path=checkpoint_file_path)
```

`Saver.save` method blocks for I/O, preventing next iterations from running.
My model's weights size is hundreds of megabytes and it takes a while to write all this stuff.

By my calculations, depending on checkpoint frequency, overall, GPU spends 5-10% time waiting for checkpoints to finish, instead of doing useful calculations. (5-10% is an equivalent of a day of calculations)

Is there a way to perform checkpoints asynchronously to reduce the waste of computational time?

Implementation sketch: first we might copy everything necessary from the device memory to host, and perform disk I/O on a separate thread. `Saver.save` would return after memcopy, without waiting for disk operations, as it is safe to train the device copy now without screwing up the checkpoint. `Saver.save` would still block on re-entry if there is I/O pending from the previous iteration.

I don't think it's currently implemented, so I am interested in possible workarounds as well. Is this idea nice enough to be a feature request on GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

You can write checkpoints asynchronously by running `saver.save()` in a separate thread. The (internal) [`SVTimerCheckpointThread`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/294442996b2aeff00b1bfdc7e7169f7cb35bbf3d/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py#L1053) is an example of code that runs `saver.save()` periodically in the background of training. Note that the [`tf.train.Supervisor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#Supervisor) is a utility class that helps with managing such background threads (also for writing TensorBoard summary logs, etc.), so you might want to use it instead.

Comment: Thank you, Derek. I am quite surprised. To clarify one more time, is it save to call `save()` in a separate thread while training is in progress? (also, considering GIL, the same question goes for a separate process). Wouldn't weight changes during training interfere with checkpoint saving? If not, what mechanism prevents it?

Comment: It's "safe" in that the process won't crash, but it's not atomic with respect to parameter updates, so you may see partially applied updates if the training runs concurrently: both across the variables and potentially within individual variables. For most models that we train by asynchronous SGD (or its variants), this is good enough, so there is no built-in mechanism for taking consistent snapshots with a `Saver` (although one could be built using the same mechanisms as `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`...).